# Database Design - Where should user location be stored

Tags: database, location

Im building a friendship website. The problem I'm having is where should I store the locations of users ( I need to store two variables [country] [state/province]).

The friendship site has a question and answer table currently that stores users attributes such as user religion , users eye color etc...

Is it appropriate to add two more questions to the userAttributes table? (see option 1 below)

1. What is your country
2. Whats is your state / Province

OR

Do country and state belong in there own table separate form the userAttributes  table. (see option 2 below)

Option 1 - userAttributes Table

```
Question                    | Answer 
What is your eye color      | blue
What is your eye color      | green
What country                | Canada
What state / province       | Alberta
What state / province       | Ontario
What country                | United States
What state / province       | New York
What state / province       | Louisiana
What state / province       | Georgia 
etc ...
```

Option 2 - ProfileLocation Table

```
Id | country       | province-state
1  | Canada        | Alberta
2  | United States | New York
3  | United States | Louisiana
```

Note : The website will have probably 900 - 1000 provinces / states so this will really fill up the userAttributes Table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two questions, and a large number of answers which are linked to each other. You should store the *answers* in two tables, which I'll refer to as `countries` and `provinces`. The `provinces` table links back to the `countries` table so you can extract the data you need easily.

This gives you

Countries

```
id   |  Name
------------------------------
1    |  USA
44   |  United Kingdom
64   |  New Zealand
```

Provinces

```
id  | Country ID | Name
1   | 1          | Oregon
2   | 1          | Arizona
3   | 1          | Kentucky
4   | 44         | London
5   | 44         | Kent
6   | 64         | Waikato
7   | 64         | Wairarapa
```

(You can fill in the rest)

A simple query will populate a `countries` drop-down menu on your web page. An AJAX call and a second simple query can populate a `provinces` drop-down on the fly (or you could send the lists when the page is loaded and use a little Javascript to populate the drop-down from there).